# Creating Google group using Directory API set Archive messages to the group

Tags: google-directory-api, google-groups

Creating bulk google Group using App engine, I need to set all groups to Archive messages to the group "Group Archive Option".

Reading through the APIs https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups there is no mentioning of enabling archiving messages on Google Group while while **creating** or **updating** a group.

Any advice on this? It would be a hassle to do this manually given that we're talking about 1000+ Groups!

Answer (score 0):

such settings you can set through group settings api:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups#resource